# Magento blank page - $this->loadlayout() seems to be not working for me

Tags: layout, magento-1.4

I have created a custom module **Acer_Laptop** and trying to display a page when following URL is hit:
http://localhost/project/aspire/check/basic

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acer_Laptop>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Acer_Laptop>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
           <Acer_Laptop>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Acer_Laptop</module>
                    <frontName>aspire</frontName>
               </args>
            </Acer_Laptop>
        </routers>
       <layout>
              <updates>
                  <aspire module="Acer_Laptop">
                      <file>aspire.xml</file>
                  </aspire>
              </updates>
          </layout>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

I've created a controller

```
class Acer_Laptop_CheckController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function basicAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

a layout file **aspire.xml** is created as defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <aspire_check_basic>
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="aspire" template="aspire/laptop/check.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </aspire_check_basic>
</layout>
```

check.phtml template

```
<h1><?php echo($this->__("Acer Laptop check")); ?></h1>
```

It only shows header when I go to http://localhost/project/aspire/check/basic. I have tried many tricks to get this work. I want header + the contents of phtml file.

If I change the layout i.e. aspire.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <basic_check>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="aspire" output="toHtml" template="aspire/laptop/check.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </basic_check>
</layout>
```

and in controller instead of `$this->loadLayout();` if I use `$this->loadLayout('basic_check');` then it shows only the contents of phtml file without the header.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to fix this.

Comment: Check the logs for the error but you might want to try `echo $this->__('Acer Laptop check')`...

Comment: @zigojacko, surprisingly there's no error.. in controller, echo $this->__('Acer Laptop check') works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout handle is `{route}_{controller}_{action}`

In your case this is: `Acer_Laptop_check_basic`, not `aspire_check_basic` and also not `basic_check`

Note that `aspire` is the front name, which only affects the URL:

```
<routers>
   <Acer_Laptop>                <---- this is the route name !!!
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Acer_Laptop</module>
            <frontName>aspire</frontName>
       </args>
    </Acer_Laptop>
</routers>
```

You might want to change the route name to `aspire` for consistency.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me to get closer. If I change the route name to aspire and use <aspire_basic_check>, I can see header + contents. However, since its very old code, I've some restrictions on changes as I'm not sure of all places where it will affect.. so instead of changing the route name to aspire, I have replaced in layout - <aspire_basic_check> by <acer_laptop_check_basic> but surprisingly this too shows header only

Comment: The layout handle is case sensitive.

Comment: thanks for pointing out.. I've changed it to <Acer_Laptop_check_basic> and cleared the cache, but it is still same --> contents of phtml are not shown

Comment: Moreover, I've also changed the route name back to <Acer_Laptop>

Comment: if it works with `aspire` route name, but not with `Acer_Laptop`, the underscore might be a problem. Never seen that in a route name.